# If I change computer, do i have to change connectionString for Entity,or just other connectionStrings ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have to can you please show me what part to change?

```
<add name="RestaurantEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataLayer.RestaurantModel.csdl|res://*/DataLayer.RestaurantModel.ssdl|res://*/DataLayer.RestaurantModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Restaurant.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just **change used conectionString** with server **where database is hosted**.

Answer (score 0):

With this connectionString. I did not think we have to change it when running on another computer. Because of `data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Restaurant.mdf;`
It told us that it will attach the available database file (Restaurant.mdf) to LocalDB\v22.0